# Why is 'Salt Asbestos Curtain' the Aperture Science motto?

Tags: portal-series

I've been looking at some valve [swag](http://store.valvesoftware.com/product.php?i=MU505) and noticed the company motto (?) on top of the Aperture Science logo.  Why is "Salt Asbestos Curtain" the company motto?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, it's not the company motto, it's an ad campaign.

Aperture Science [was a shower curtain company](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Aperture_Science) producing deadly shower Curtains before they became better known for developing the portal gun.

Basically, you're reading the phrase the wrong way. It's not "Salt Asbestos Curtain", it's "Salt", "Asbestos", and "Curtains". I'm not sure quite where the Salt comes in.

Comment: it's not one of their motto's though, just a marketing line of what products they made in 1940.

Comment: The enrichment centre was in an old salt mine, if that helps.

Comment: By reading a framed newspaper in the one of the lower areas you can find that Johnson was a billionare and the facility is in a abandoned salt mine. Thus, Salt.

Answer (score 13):

Its not one of their motto's, it was just a marketing line of the products they were selling in 1940, their motto's are:

- Courage is Not the Absence of Fear
- There's a hole in the sky through which things can fly
- We do what we must because we can
- The best damn applied sciences company on Earth (informal)
- A clear picture of the future
- A clear focus on the future

As listed [here](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Aperture_Science).

Answer (score 3):

its the market campaign and salt is there because old aperture was built in and old salt mine and when they went drilling to make the place bigger they had to mine the salt so cave sold it

Answer (score 2):

Salt: Aperture Science is located in a re-purposed Michigan salt mine.
Asbestos: "All these testing spheres are made out of asbestos.  Keeps out the rats." - Cave Johnson
Curtains: Aperture Science started out as Aperture Fixtures, a company that made shower curtains for all branches of the military except the navy.